# Java - Invalid enum value not falling into default in switch block

Tags: java, enums

I put an invalid value in `config.properties`:

```
# Browser: CHROME, CHROME_NOHEAD, FF32, FF32_NOHEAD, FF64, FF64_NOHEAD
# EDGE, IE32, IE64
browser=oPerA
```

I set up the switch with a default clause:

```
public class ServiceHook {
    public enum Browser {
        CHROME, CHROME_NOHEAD, FF32, FF32_NOHEAD, FF64, FF64_NOHEAD, EDGE, IE32, IE64
    }

    public void setUp() throws Throwable {
        String browserConfig = Configuration.readKey("browser"); // Reads the String from the config file
        Browser browser = Browser.valueOf(browserConfig.toUpperCase());

        switch (browser) {
        case CHROME:
            // Do something for each case
            break;
        case CHROME_NOHEAD: break;
        case FF32: break;
        case FF32_NOHEAD: break;
        case FF64: break;
        case FF64_NOHEAD: break;
        case EDGE: break;
        case IE32: break;
        case IE64: break;
        default:
            // Do something for unsupported browser
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting below exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
>   jcucumberng.steps.defs.ServiceHook.Browser.OPERA

Any advice why it does not trigger default clause?

Comment: Because it triggers an `IllegalArgumentException`, instead, before the switch. See the stack trace, and the Javadoc.

Comment: the problem is here `Browser browser = Browser.valueOf(browserConfig.toUpperCase());`, not in the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't get that far.

It's the `Browser browser = Browser.valueOf(browserConfig.toUpperCase());` that throws the Exception. You have to put that in a try-catch block to handle invalid values.

Comment: Thanks! Also added an if-check to make sure `browser` isn't null before the switch. The default clause rather lost its purpose though.

Comment: @silver Not really, the `default` statement still has its merit when you extend your enum but don't implement your behavior for the new value yet.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in `Browser browser = Browser.valueOf(browserConfig.toUpperCase());` (7<sup>th</sup> line),
 So

**Debug at this line 'Browser.valueOf(browserConfig.toUpperCase());'** statement to see what exactly happening(see what value is in browser)